# Replacing options in Scala with default values if there is nothing there

Tags: scala

Suppose I have an item of the type `(Option[Long], Option[Long], Option[Long], Option[Long], Option[Long])`, and I want to convert it to an item of type `(Long, Long, Long, Long, Long)`.  I want each coordinate to contain the value of the option (if the option contains a "Some" value), or be zero otherwise.

Usually if I have an item of type `Option[Long]`, I'd do something like

```
item match {
    case Some(n) => n
    case None => 0
}
```

But I can't do that with a 5 coordinate item unless I want to list out all 32 possibilities.  What can I do instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
item match {
  case (a, b, c, d, e) => (a.getOrElse(0), b.getOrElse(0), c.getOrElse(0), d.getOrElse(0), e.getOrElse(0))
}
```

Obviously this isn't very generic.  For that you'll probably want to look at Shapeless but I'll leave that answer to the resident experts. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using Shapeless you could do:

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.std.tuple._
import poly._

object defaultValue extends Poly1 {
  implicit def defaultOptionLong = at[Option[Long]](_.getOrElse(0L))
}

val tuple : (Option[Long], Option[Long], Option[Long], Option[Long], Option[Long]) = 
  (Some(1L), None, Some(3L), Some(4L), None)

tuple.map(defaultValue)
// (Long, Long, Long, Long, Long) = (1,0,3,4,0)
```

You need to explicitly specify type `Option[Int]` if you don't use `Option.apply` (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127542/why-does-mapping-over-an-hlist-of-optiont-not-work)).

```
(Option(1L), Option(2L)).map(defaultValue) 
// (Long, Long) = (1,2)

(Some(3L), Some(4L)).map(defaulValue) // does not compile
val t : (Option[Long], Option[Long]) = (Some(3L), Some(4L))
t.map(defaultValue) 
// (Long, Long) = (3,4)

(Option(5), None).map(defaultValue) // does not compile
val t2 (Option[Long], Option[Long]) = (Option(5), None)
t2.map(defaultValue) 
// (Long, Long) = (5,0)
```

We could also provide default values for other types:

```
object defaultValue extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseLong = at[Option[Long]](_.getOrElse(0L))
  implicit def caseInt = at[Option[Int]](_.getOrElse(0))
  implicit def caseString = at[Option[String]](_.getOrElse("scala"))
}

val tuple2 : (Option[Int], Option[Long], Option[String]) = (None, None, None)
tuple2.map(defaultValue)
// (Int, Long, String) = (0,0,scala)
```

---

**Edit:** The problem with the need of explicit declaration of `Some(5L)` as `Option[Long]` can be solved using generics in the poly function :

```
objec defaultValue extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseLong[L <: Option[Long]] = at[L](_.getOrElse(0L))
  implicit def caseInt[I <: Option[Int]] = at[I](_.getOrElse(0))
  implicit def caseString[S <: Option[String]] = at[S](_.getOrElse("scala"))
}

(Some("A"), Some(1), None: Option[Int], None: Option[String]).map(defaultValue)
// (String, Int, Int, String) = (A,1,0,scala)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
val res = for {
   a <- item._1.orElse(0L)
   b <- item._2.orElse(0L)
   c <- item._3.orElse(0L)
   d <- item._4.orElse(0L)
   e <- item._5.orElse(0L)
} yield (a, b, c, d, e)
```

Not the nicest but easy to implement and understand.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
item.productIterator.collect{
   case Some(a: Int) => a
   case _            => 0
}.toList match {
    case List(a,b,c,d,e) => (a,b,c,d,e)
    case _ => (0,0,0,0,0) //or throw exception depending on your logic
}
```